# Two unrelated questions: 1. Output of Series[] for function, 2. Output conditional answers as if not conditional

Tags: functions, series-expansion, output, conditional

As mentioned in the title, I have two questions.

**1.** I have code that looks similar to:

```
Series[1/Sqrt[x],{x,1,2}]
(* This gives 1 - (x-1)/2 + (3/8)(x-1)^2 + O[x-1]^3 *)
f[x_]:=%
```

I want this to be equivalent to defining

```
f[x_]:=1 - (x-1)/2 + (3/8)*(x-1)^2
```

but instead Mathematica doesn't seem to know what do do with it. Any ideas on how to accomplish this sort of thing? More generally, I often find this kind of problem, where I want to define a function or variable from the output of a previous expression, but I don't know deeply enough how Mathematica works to accomplish this. Any advice?

**2.** Frequently, especially when integrating or solving differential equations, Mathematica outputs its answers as ConditionalExpression[answer, conditions]. Obviously there are good reasons for this, but sometimes it just makes the Mathematica document look messy. Does anyone know of a way to tell Mathematica, "if the answer is a conditional expression, output the answer as if the conditions are met"?

For example, the code

```
Integrate[1/(x^2+y^2),{y,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

outputs

```
ConditionalExpression[Pi Sqrt[1/x^2], Im[x^2] != 0 || Re[x^2]>=0]
```

I could obviously get around this by adding `Assumptions->Re[x^2]>=0`, but the assumptions clause will be different for every expression I evaluate. I want something more general that I can write to *always* skip the `ConditionalExpression`, e.g., something like

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {z, -Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions->"Conditions are all satisfied"]
```

Thanks very much for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate questions.

Comment: Use `Normal` on the output to get an "usable" form ( Q1 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the second question: you could change ConditionalExpression itself.

```
Unprotect[ConditionalExpression]

ConditionalExpression[a_, ___] := a
```

but this is potentially dangerous. Who knows where else ConditionalExpression is being used? So, a safer alternative is just change the way it's being output

```
Unprotect[ConditionalExpression]

Format[ConditionalExpression[a_, ___]] := a
```

Another alternative, with side effects that I can't oversee and that's probably too stupid to consider (but that works in your case) would be the simple:

```
$Assumptions := {_ -> True}

Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* π Sqrt[1/x^2] *)
```

Perhaps the safest approach would be using a version of Michael E2's comment in combination with `$Post`:

```
$Post = (#/.ConditionalExpression->First &)
```

Comment: It seemed like the OP wanted something that would work on a whole series of operations without intervention of the user. Putting /. ConditionalExpression -> First behind every expression would not really meet the requirement.

Comment: It works in all cases, though - the OP seemed willing to add assumptions, just not different and unpredictable ones each time.  Frankly, I think the question should be split, edited or even deleted.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree

Answer (score 1):

Use `Normal` with `Series`

```
f[x_] = Series[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 1, 2}] // Normal
```

> 1 + (1 - x)/2 + (3/8)*(-1 + x)^2

Use `GenerateConditions -> False` with `Integrate`

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2), {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> Pi*Sqrt[1/x^2]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, and perhaps more generally, conditions can be eliminated by prepending `First`, as in

```
First@Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```